# Angular Reactive Forms - Exclude null values on submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have an angular reactive form as below:

```
this.newMeasurementForm = new FormGroup({
  'type' : new FormControl(null, []),
  'measurementDate' : new FormControl(null, []),
  'measuredBy' : new FormControl(null, []),
  'bloodOxygen' : new FormGroup({
    'hemoglobine': new FormControl(),
    'hematocriet': new FormControl(),
    'oximetry': new FormControl(),
    'deviceTypeOximetry' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeBloodOxygen' : new FormControl(null, [])
  }),
  'gripStrength' : new FormGroup({
    'gripLeft' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'gripRight' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'gripAperture' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceType' : new FormControl(null, [])

  }),
  'lungFunction' : new FormGroup({
    'fev' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'fev1' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'fev2575' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'pef' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'fivc' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'smoking' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'cigarettesPerDay' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'yearsOfSmoking' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'packYears' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'lungAge' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'intervention' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceType' : new FormControl(null, [])
  }),
  'enduranceCapacity' : new FormGroup({
    'pulse' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'power' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'heartRate' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'vo2max' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceType' : new FormControl(null, [])
  }),
  'generalMeasurements' : new FormGroup({
    'height' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'weight' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'bmi' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'circumNavel' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'circumButtocks' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'bai' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'navelButtocks' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeGeneralMeasurements' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeCircumNavel' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeCircumButtocks' : new FormControl(null, [])
  }),
  'measurementGlucoseHeart' : new FormGroup({
    'hoursFasting' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'sysBP' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'diaBP' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'totalCholestrol' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'hdl' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'triglycerides' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'totalCholestrolHDL' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'ldl' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'hb1ac' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'glucose' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'crp' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeBP' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeCholestrol' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeHb1Ac' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeGlucose' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceTypeCRP' : new FormControl(null, [])
  }),
  'physicalActivity' : new FormGroup({
    'vigorous' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'moderate' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'netActivity' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'walking' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'stepCount' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'sitting' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceType' : new FormControl(null, [])
  }),
  'bodyComposition' : new FormGroup({
    'fatPercent' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'fatMass' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'muscleMass' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'hipWaistRatio' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'visceralFat' : new FormControl(null, []),
    'deviceType' : new FormControl(null, [])
  })
});
```

Multiple fields in this form can be empty/null. I want to exclude all the empty field when I submit the form. Currently, the `form.values` return all the fields with empty fields set to null. I want to get rid of null properties from the form values. I have tried following code:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key =>  data[key] != null ? fields[key] = data[key] : key);
```

But it only excludes the empty field on the top level and not in the inner group. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your solution in recursive way:

let's say this is your form object with nested objects:

```
const newMeasurementForm = {
  "type: "X",
   value: null,
  "bodyComposition": {
    "a":"b",
    "c": null,
  }
};
```

You can use call the below function:

```
const removeNull = (formObject) => {
  Object.keys(formObject).forEach(key => {
     if (formObject[key] && typeof formObject[key] === "object") {
       removeNull(formObject[key]);
     } else if (formObject[key] === null) {
       delete formObject[key];
     }
   });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. When trying your answer, I am getting `';' expected.ts(1005)` error on `const removeNull = (formObject) => {` line (I am new to Angular, don't know how to fix it).